# Im trying to pull data from an API and render it to my HTML using Javascript. I think Im close

Tags: javascript

Ive been trying to pull data from an "Current News Source" API structured in JSON using Javascript. Im in the testing phases right now.

On click I want to have my HTML element named "title" updated to the "title from the News JSON file. Heres what I have so far..

The HTML

```
<h3 class="title text-center" id="title" name="title">Russia accuses US of interfering in vote</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-white bg-muted" id="searchButton">Search</button>
```

The Javascript

```
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", getRandomTitle)

function getRandomTitle() {
    fetch('https://api.currentsapi.services/v1/latest-news?q=keywords=Biden&apiKey=12345678910')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        title.innerHTML = data.news.title

});

}
```

The JSON file

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "news": [
    {
      "id": "4e67842f-018d-4744-aa02-d21da55c278d",
      "title": "Early Matter Domination from Long-Lived Particles in the Visible Sector. (arXiv:2108.13136v2 [hep-ph] UPDATED)"

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.news` is an array of object, to access the specific *title* you have to use the corresponding *index*.

Also, I will suggest you to use [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to set the plain text (not *htmlString*) to a HTML element:

```
title.textContent = data.news[0].title; // get the title from first news object
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it all settled, you're awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

From the JSON file, it looks like `data.news` is an array.
Try `data.news[0].title`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `data.news[0].title` because it seems you are getting array of object as result in `data.news`

```
function getRandomTitle() {
fetch('https://api.currentsapi.services/v1/latest-news?q=keywords=Biden&apiKey=12345678910')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    title.innerHTML = data.news[0].title   // Specify the index for the array

});
```